# Laravel php version for open application?

Tags: frameworks, laravel-4

I want to create a php application that can be used by many users, As laravel 4 requries 5.3.7  i am confused weather to use it or not because many of the users may not have the php version supported as they will be using shared hosting.

How to overcome this ? Is it by using older version of laravel or some other solution please help me. I am really intersted in using laravel cause of its robust nature.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, depending on what your application is, it's probably enough to think that most users are either already going to be on PHP 5.3.7+ or they will be willing to upgrade to the latest version or a more recent version of PHP.

When PHP 5.3.20 was released, there was [an extremely public announcement](http://php.net/releases/5_3_20.php) that PHP 5.3 was going to be EOL'd after March 2013.

It's now obviously past March 2013.

People *should* have moved to PHP 5.4 by now. If your application is a one of a kind, or the best in it's class, then you *should not* need to worry about what version of PHP is being operated on, as people should either

1. be running PHP version > 5.3.20
2. be able to upgrade to a PHP version > 5.3.20

The Laravel dependancy on PHP 5.3 is a nice one, and to be honest, with all of the new features and general code style of Laravel being introduced, I would not be surprised if the version requirement is increased to PHP 5.4 "soon" (in say the next 6-12 months).

If you want to create an application used by many users, simply advise them that there is a minimum requirement for PHP 5.3.7. This is not too unusual for web applications.

For example, a very popular PHP forum [phpBB has required PHP 5.3.3 since March 2012](https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=2152375).